# CSS style.css file not being loaded by HTML

Tags: html, css, github-pages

Well this is embarrassing. I've not been able to get the following css files to render. I'm using github pages to try and teach kids how websites work. When we got to the CSS section, I created this file called style.css For some reason I can't get it to render the css file. I've tried to do a hard refresh, clearing cache, there is only 1 folder and everything is in it. It's funny because kids have emulate what I typed in and got the right result. What am I missing? Am I missing an incredibly obvious thing? https://nlnrose.github.io/Mr_Rose_Website_Project_23-24/

```
body{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;/*#ebe1ca;*/
  }
h1{
  background-color:#11f2ee;
}
```

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Watercolor Painting</title>
    <!-- Replace the content in the following line with your name. -->
    <meta name="author" content="Mr. Rose">
    <link rel=“stylesheet”  href="./style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body style="margin-left: 30px;margin-right: 30px;">
    <!-- Replace the lines in this body with your content. -->
    <h1>Watercolor Painting</h1>
    <h2>My Techniques</h2>
    <p style="text-align:center;">There are <b>2</b> major kinds of watercolor painting. There is wet on wet and wet on dry.</p>
    <h2>My Paintings</h2>
    <p style="text-align:center;">
      Here you will see a picture of one of my paintings.<br/>
      <img style="text-align:center;" 
        src="snapinsta.jpg" 
        href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEXfQKabQGI" 
        width="500" height="625" 
        alt="Watercolor hummingbird on yupo paper."/>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-left: 50px;margin-right: 50px;">
      <a href="secondpage.html">More</a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEXfQKabQGI">A useful video</a>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have also tried removing the inline style for the body, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will hurt now... You used the wrong quotation marks for *rel=“stylesheet”*. Change it to *rel="stylesheet"*.

This is what it currently looks like using the browser developer tools:
[image: wrong quotes]